# Google Analytics - How to know who uses the API?

Tags: google-analytics

I searched and didn't find the answer... 
I work with a lot of several people, and they have a lot of user accounts on GA.

I tried to access the real time API of GA, and I received an error : too much calls already done today.

But unfortunately I don't know who is responsible for the huge amount of calls. 
It's by the way not really safe for my data.

How can I do ? Is it possible to know who does API calls ? To manage the rights to use the API ?

Thanks a lot !

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The only way to manage API permissions is to remove users from the view/property/account. And the only way to know who is doing the API calls is to ask around (email addresses are visible in the account settings).

I do agree  though that API permission management would be a useful feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)